# AngularJS http request to postmark it returns this -> "data":null,"status":-1

Tags: angularjs, curl, postmark

When I send request to postmark using http in angular it returns null.
I am trying to use angular to send email using postmark restful api, did I missed something, or is there any other way to send email using angular and postmark?

Anyway here's my code:

```
  var data = {
    From : 'test@gmail.com',
    ReplyTo : 'test@gmail.com',
    To : 'test@gmail.com',
    subject : 'Test Email Subject',
    HtmlBody : '&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p style="color: red"&gt;Test&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;'
  };

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($http){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.postmarkapp.com/email',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {  
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Postmark-Server-Token': '*************'
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alert('success');
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Has postmark allowed CORS? If not, you can't send AJAX requests to postmark.

Answer (score 1):

I work on Postmark.

I don't have a lot of experience with Angular, but if I understand correctly, you're initiating an AJAX request from the client-side.

For your security, Postmark doesn't allow CORS requests, so in order to send an email to postmark, you'll need to proxy the request through an endpoint in your backend.

If you contact support, we'll be happy to provide code snippets to do this in your language of choice where possible.